# Make horizontally scrollable table in bootstrap using Grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen questions like this but none of them worked for me. So here is my Code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
    <tr>
        {partners_info}
        <td>
            <a href="{link_partner}">
                <div style=" background-image: url('{img_partner}');" class="give_size">
                </div>
            </a>
        </td>
        {/partners_info}
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<style>
    .give_size {
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-size: 200px auto;
         background-position: center;
         height: 200px;
     }
</style>
```

Basiccly I'm using codeigniter and bootstrap and [Here os my website where you can clearly see the problem](http://pottersapp.com/IQ) you can scroll down and see the it. I want to make this table scrollable horizontally but pictures to take exact width as provided in code.Hope you can help and  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check my example to make , anything scrollable we need to give it a height and use overflow-x or overflow-y and than we need to add what we want when the overflow happens in your case you wanted to make it scroll able therefore the code looks like `overflow-y:scroll;`

```css
tr {
width: 100%;
display: inline-table;
}

table{
 height:300px; 
}
tbody{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<head>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<table class="table table-striped">
<thead><tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr><td>..</td><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```